# Multiple Google Analytic accounts integration into single iOS project

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics

I have successfully integrated Google Analytics in my swift app.  I'm using cocoapods as outlined on google's site -> 
[Add Analytics to Your iOS App](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/?ver=swift#get-config)

My problem arises with integrating it independently into an SDK that has been integrated into my host app.

I have a separate GoogleService-Info.plist file for the SDK.
I'm also not allowed to add another Objective-C Bridging Header to the SDK target.

So, how does one integrate Google Analytics from one's own Google Analytic account into a distributed SDK regardless of the host app's Google Analytic integration?